# Custom Elements are not getting marked when hovering over them with Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a main html file where i embedd Web Components.
When debugging I noticed, that my Custom Elements are not marked, when I hover over them. [image]

Im also not able to set the size of the custom html element from an outisde css.

Here is my code:

view.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="view.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script defer src="widget-uhr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <widget-uhr></widget-uhr>
    <widget-uhr></widget-uhr>
    <widget-uhr></widget-uhr>
    <button>View Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

widget-uhr.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="widget-uhr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <button>Widget Button1</button>
    <button>Widget Button2</button>
    <button>Widget Button3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

view.css

```
body{
    display:block;
}
button{
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

widget-uhr.css

```
body{
color:green;
background-color: gray;
}

div{
    color:blue;
    background-color: gray;
}

button{
    background-color: red;
}
```

widget-uhr.js

```
fetch( "widget-uhr.html" )
    .then( stream => stream.text() )
    .then( text => 
        customElements.define( "widget-uhr", class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super()
                this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open'} )
                    .innerHTML = text


            }
        } )
    )
```

Is the reason maybe because I inject my html from the widget via fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a Custom Element is *inline*, so it won't be marked in Dev Tools.

To get it marked, you should define its CSS `display` propery to `block` or `inline-block`.

From inside its Shadow DOM, use the `:host` CSS pseudo-class.

In **widget-uhr.css**:

```
:host { display: block }
```

Or, from the main document, use the custom element name.

In **view.css**:

```
widget-uhr { display: block }
```

Comment: Both versions work well. Which would you favor? I think I will go with the second, because the html page which includes the widget shouldn't care about the display property.

Comment: @J.Doe it depends if I consider that the property is intrasec or not. If you want to define a background color or a border you should use :host. Anyway the second solution override the first if both are used.

Answer (score 0):

## Style from outside

> Im also not able to set the size of the custom html element from an outisde css.

With Shadow DOM CSS selectors don't cross the shadow boundary. We have style encapsulation from the outside world.

You could include the rule inside the style element in the shadow tree.

```
 <style>
   @import url( 'view.css' )
 </style>
```

[More information here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

## Chrome Inspector

> When debugging I noticed, that my Custom Elements are not marked, when I hover over them.
> You have to enable Shadow DOM inspector first.

1. Open your dev tools with F12
2. Click on the three dots on the top right
3. Click on Settings
4. Enable option "Show user agents Shadow DOM" under Elements category

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im not trying to style something in the shadow dom. I want to style the <widget-uhr> element which contains the shadow dom (Setting it to a fixed size e.g.).
The Setting for the Chrome Inspector did not resolved the issue.